# How can I track "Magic Weapon"s cooldown?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Wizard's magic weapon states that it increases damage by 10%, lasts 5 minutes. However it doesn't give a duration timer near my health orb like similar buffs.

How do I know when my magic weapon has expired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Magic weapon](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/magic-weapon) (and all its runed varieties) has a pretty distinctive glow, and when the glow fades, so too has the buff.

But you shouldn't even need to keep track of it. Magic Weapon costs a measly 25 arcane power, which is 2.5 seconds worth of regen or less! I think the real solution is to get in the habit of casting Magic Weapon at the end of every fight, because there's no reason *not* to refresh the duration.

Between frequent recasting and the buff's 5-minute duration, you'll never have to worry about letting the buff drop.

And for the future, [the 1.0.3 patch will add in a buff timer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5593230830?page=10#189) (point 7).

> We're adding a buff icon for Magic Weapon in 1.0.3. We don't intend to add one for Familiar as it's a physically visible object on your screen. Magic Weapon was actually impossible to tell if it was up in quite a few cases. We'll be continuing to watch skills and buff icons, though, as there could be some situations where we need to expose more.

Comment: Eh, it's a relatively annoying UI issue to my mind... speaking as someone who needs Power Auras in WoW to remind him to turn all his buffs on all the time, because otherwise I inevitably forget.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep an eye on the weapon (it should be blue as long as it's in effect) but otherwise there's no timer than I know of.