# Why doesn't magic weapon have a buff indicator?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I track “Magic Weapon”s cooldown?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67097/how-can-i-track-magic-weapons-cooldown)

I've noticed playing on my wizard that most of my skills show a buff with an indicator of how much time is left, just above the hotbar 1-4 spots, but whenver I cast magic weapon, nothing shows up.  I see the dps change in my stats window, but never know when it's dropped during combat.  Is there some way to track how long the spell has left, or do I just need to keep recasting it before I run into combat to make sure its up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only visual indicator that I have noticed is the lightning/sparks that begin radiating from your weapon when it is active. That won't tell you how much time the spell has left, but it's at least a visual indicator of it being active or not.

It is very odd that it does not put a buff above your hotbar like other buffs.

My habit is the same as yours, when out of combat I simply periodically refresh my passive abilities such as magic weapon, ice armor, familiar, etc.